# What is the correct way to use androidx dropdownPreference?

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx

I'm using dropdown preference but app crashes each time it tries to infalte. What should be entryValues and entries filed? official doc does not explain about xml usage. Tested on api 25 and 21.

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/Time">

    <androidx.preference.DropDownPreference
        android:key="dropdown"
        android:title="@string/waitTime"
        android:entryValues="@array/planets_array"
        android:entries="@array/times"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
        />


</androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

string.xml:

```
 <resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>

<integer-array name="times">
    <item>5</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>20</item>

</integer-array>
</resources>
```

Log:

```
Process: com.example.detector, PID: 11439
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class androidx.preference.DropDownPreference
    ...
androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.setPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:377)
    at com.example.breathdetector.ui.customization.CustomizationFragment.onCreatePreferences(CustomizationFragment.java:24)
 androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
   ...
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   ...androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.setPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:377) 
    at com.example.breathdetector.ui.customization.CustomizationFragment.onCreatePreferences(CustomizationFragment.java:24) 
    at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:160) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the sample:

[arrays xml](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/blob/master/PreferencesKotlin/app/src/main/res/xml/widgets.xml)

[preferences xml](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/blob/master/PreferencesKotlin/app/src/main/res/xml/widgets.xml)

Hard to tell from the stacktrace, but it might be because you are using an integer array - I think `DropDownPreference` only works with string arrays for both entries and entry values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Link is 404. please update